# Windows 11, Remote Desktop Connection. Save passwords for TWO accounts on one server?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11, remote-access, remote, remote-control

What if I want to use two accounts for one RDP server? It seems that if I save the password for even one account, I cannot use another account, so that I have to type the password every time I want to connect to the server using either of the accounts. This is tedious.

What I want is saving the passwords for both of the accounts, and connect to the server using any of the accounts with one click. At first I thought I could create connection settings file for each of them, and then connect by double clicking them, but it seems that there is no way to save the password in the settings file.

Is it impossible?

[image]

Comment: Does it solve your problem, if you save the connection? This means, you will have to *.rdp files with different username/password

Comment: @MarkusMeyer How to save password in the RDP file? The GUI has no such option.

Comment: @MarkusMeyer is correct. You can also download the windows remote desktop connection manager tool from microsoft and then you can have multiple instances of a specific machine: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rdcman

Comment: @Narzard That tool can do what I wanted, but the tool's UI is not very good. It would be better if I double click some sort of file in the Start Menu or Desktop and connect to it directly. You and Meyer said "\*.rdp" files can do it, but that tool seems to only allow "\*.rdg" files. How can I save each single connection with saved password as an "*.rdp" file?